# Can I support all ES5, ES6, ES7 features?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, ecmascript-2016

Are there any ways to config a Reactjs project to support all ES5, ES6, ES7 features?

I mean that I can write all the ES5, ES6, ES7 syntaxes.

I am using babel and webpack.

Comment: Sure, just use `ES7` (which is a superset of the previous versions) in your babel settings?

Comment: So, how can I set babel up?

Comment: Have you considered reading its documentation or tutorial? If yes, please show us the results of your efforts so that we can help you fix the problems in them ("post code!"), otherwise head to a search engine.

Comment: https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/

Comment: Babel preset: Latest

Comment: Hello! Please accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with the Babel [preset-latest](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-latest). It contains `ES6`, `ES7` and `ES8` ([`async/await`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-async-to-generator)).

See the doc to [how to install it](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-latest/#install) and [how to disable `ES8`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-latest/#usage-options) if you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you will find more information about setting up ES7 using babel + webpack:

http://jamesknelson.com/using-es6-in-the-browser-with-babel-6-and-webpack/